# how can i get my added usercontrol properties from flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, controls

I am using flowLayoutPanel and adding my custom user controls to it, I can add mu usercontrol to it but i don't know how can it use it after adding.

in this part i add my user controls:

```
...
ExtensionUserControl extension = new ExtensionUserControl(this, AMI_ClientInstance);
//Add Obj Name (Extension Number)
extension.ExtensionNumber = Obj.ObjName;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(extension as ExtensionUserControl);
...
```

and another place i want to have the properties of my added user control, i try to user this code but it get error, It says that can not convert windows control to ExtensionUserControl

```
ExtensionUserControl extension = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[1];
```

please totally tell me how can i have my user control properties after adding it to panel?

thanks

Comment: Do you use the WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Controls[1] is ExtensionUserControl?
I think that:

```
foreach(Control ctl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
     if(ctl is ExtensionUserControl)
       {
            (ExtensionUserControl)ctl......//do something u want
       }
}
```

I'm not test it yet, just thinking, sorry if it doesn't work